# how to get alert when particular job is executed in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have created a job that contain the command "select * from employ" from user databse.

when this query executed succesfully i hav to get alert by mail.how to do this

Answer (score 3):

Follow instructions here (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/randyp/archive/2009/03/04/60863.aspx), but lastly check 'success' instead of 'failed'.

Citation:

> - Run SQL Server Surface Area Configuration - > Surface Area Configuration for features -> 
>     Select Database Mail - > Check Enable Database mail stored procedures.
> - Open SQL Management Studio - > Management - > Database mail - > Configure SMTP Settings.
> - Go to SQL Server Agent - > Operators - > Create New Operator
> - Go to SQL Job - > In the Notifications, Check email and select the Operator. You can either
>     select  the option to send notification if job fails / succeeds/ completed.

More about SQL mail:
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/email_functionality_p1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of notification options in the job's properties available in SQL Server Management Studio.

For email notifications you need to configure the Server with information to [enable it to send emails](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177408.aspx).